# How can I copy files in C without platform dependency?

Tags: c, multiplatform

It looks like this question is pretty simple but I can't find the clear solution for copying files in C without platform dependency.

I used a system() call in my open source project for creating a directory, copying files and run external programs. It works very well in Mac OS X and other Unix-ish systems, but it fails on Windows. The problem was:

```
system( "cp a.txt destination/b.txt" );
```

- Windows uses backslashes for path separator. (vs slashes in Unix-ish)
- Windows uses 'copy' for the internal copy command. (vs cp in Unix-ish)

How can I write a copying code without dependency?

( Actually, I wrote macros to solve this problems, but it's not cool. http://code.google.com/p/npk/source/browse/trunk/npk/cli/tests/testutil.h, L22-56 )

Comment: Problem is not dangling on 'copying' as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the C standard library functions in [stdio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h).

In particular, `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fclose` will be sufficient.

Be sure to include the `b` ("binary") option in the flags to `fopen`.

[edit]

Unfortunately, the file names themselves (forward-slashes vs. back-slashes) are still platform dependent.  So you will need some sort of `#ifdef` or similar to deal with that.

Or you can use a [cross-platform toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform#Cross-platform_programming_toolkits_and_environments).

Comment: Thank you for answering. But cross-platform toolkits are too big for my tiny project. Isn't there any simple solution to resolve slash-problem?

Comment: Since directory organizations are platform-specific, there isn't a completely trivial way.  However, at the API level, Windows accepts slashes or backslashes in pathnames (it is the cmd.exe shell that requires backslashes).  So, as long as your Unix names never contain a backslash (and probably not colon either), you'll be OK.

Comment: @Jonathan:  OK, I admit I did not know that.  What about file names with slashes in them, which are legal on Windows?  Maybe I should just try it sometime :-)

Comment: The slashes are treated as directory separators; a pathname component cannot contain a slash (or backslash) on Windows.  Colons get used with drive letters (`C:\Program Files\SomeThing`), special devices `:NUL`, and [alternate data streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) or 'resource forks'.

Comment: @Jonathan: I could have sworn I had seen files on Windows with names like "Performance Report 01/02/99".  Or maybe that was an old Mac...  I am sure I saw it somewhere and it caused problems with certain Unix file servers.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks. So should I use posix file functions to copy files? is there any other ways to do it? Because copying files, creating directories are not a feature of my project, they are only used for unit-testing. (to prepare test samples)

Comment: That's because classic Macs didn't use / for separators but ":".  If you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename , you'll find a LOT of characters reserved that you never would have guessed!

Comment: @lqez:  `fopen` etc. are not just POSIX; they are part of the C standard itself.  So they are perfectly portable.  (Although I do not believe the C standard provides any way to create a directory.)

Answer (score 9):

The `system()` function is a lot more trouble than it's worth; it invokes the shell in a seperate proccess, and should usually be avoided.

Instead `fopen()` `a.txt` and `dest/b.text`, and use `getc()`/`putc()` to do the copying (because the standard library is more likely to do page-aligned buffering than you)

```
FILE *src = fopen("a.txt", "rb");
FILE *dst = fopen("dest/b.txt", "wb");
int i;
for (i = getc(src); i != EOF; i = getc(src))
{
    putc(i, dst);
}
fclose(dst);
fclose(src);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But It doesn't resolve the path separator problem.

Comment: According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77859s1t(v=VS.71).aspx path separators are a `system()` problem, not an `fopen()` one. It fails in system because of the shell invocation.

Comment: @Dave: shouldn't those be `fclose()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard C library `stdio.h`. First open input file for reading using `fopen(inputFilename, "rb")` and open output file for writing using `fopen(outputFilename, "wb")`, copy the content using `fread` and `fwrire`. Then close both files using `fclose`.